# Extract URL from .url file

Tags: python, python-2.7, url

Is it possible to read the actual URL from a `.url`file, as described [here](http://www.fmtz.com/formats/url-file-format/article), with Python?

In the following image for instance, I can easily print *mapbox-OSM Bright- A Carto template for OpenStreetMap data* but I would also like to extract the actual URL: https://github.com/mapbox/osm-bright

[image]

I need to extract hundreds of URLs and I am currently using a batch file to get the job done, but I would much rather do it with Python. I am using Python 2.7.11 but 3 would be a possibility as well.

Comment: What is a `.url` file? If it only contains text, please [edit] your question and include the content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you mean a URL file as described [here](http://www.fmtz.com/formats/url-file-format/article). Those files have a syntax similar to .ini-files and can probably be parsed like this:

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('example.url')

try:
    url = config.get('InternetShortcut', 'URL')  # Classic URL Format
except ConfigParser.NoOptionError:
    url = config.get('DEFAULT', 'BASEURL')  # Extended URL Format
```

Comment: Quick answer and doing exactly what I wanted; you just saved me a lot of time! Glad I finally posted this. A few downvotes, as expected, but also a person who was ready to help :-)